# After a ajax success, The Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

After I send a Ajax request and it's successful. The jquery.hover() doesn't work with new part of page.

Is there way to reload the script without reloading the div via another ajax request, so that it works with the new part of the page.

Comment: Can you give more details about what you want to do when ajax success..

Comment: Add content, then allow that content to be responsive with the javascript code already loaded on the page prior to the ajax..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover) on dynamic elements as it is not an event handler, you need to use delegated event handling for [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave) events

`.hover()` is a short hand for using mouseenter and mouseleave, but it will attach the handlers to only those elements which are present in the dom at the time of execution

ex

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '<selector>', function(){
    //do something
}).on('mouseleave', '<selector>', function(){
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have added the hover action on $(document).ready(); As the new page content wasnt there when page load, you have to rebind the hover action after the new content is updated via ajax.

Comment: How would I implement this into multiply boxs with the same class?

Comment: Use a common class. ie class='someClass'. So after div updated, bind on selector $(".someClass"). So all the boxes with class "someClass" will be binded with the action.

Answer (score 0):

Since the new part is dynamically added, jquery hover won't work with that.

Try this

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'selector', function(){
        // Code to perform on mouse enter
}).on('mouseleave', 'selector', function(){
       // code to perform on mouse leave (This is optional)
})
```